# I want to create an event in my calendar,how can i do this?

Tags: ios, xcode

hi I'm new in iPhone development.I saw some code for creating new event but most of them have ,Alert repeated ,URL section  my question is how can I custom them, I mean How can I remove them and add some new sections?

Can any body suggest solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Check this it may help you.there is tapku calendar library for iOS and you can easily customize this.

Comment: please show me how it is work???

Comment: please tell me the code

Comment: tapku library is used to embed the calender in iOS and you can easily customize this @DeepakKumar